# How Do I store downloaded pdf files to Mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, store

I download the some of pdf and stored in directory. Need to insert them into mongo database with python code so how could i do these. Need to store them by making three columns (pdf_name, pdf_ganerateDate, FlagOfWork)like that.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial helps: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/introduction-mongodb-python

Comment: @Niels Henkens, these tutorial is showing how to insert documents but i need to insert pdf files by making three different folders. so how can i do these

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GridFS`. Please check [this URL](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.8/examples/gridfs.html).
It will help you to store any file to mongoDb and get them. In other collection you can save file metadata.

Comment: Need to store pdf file(which is stored in directory) on mongodb. that tutorial showing about name of file